# Query SQLite array after update

Tags: iphone, arrays, sqlite, uitableview

I have a tab bar application with 2 UITableViews. In Tab 1 I have a UITableView populated with an array of Todo objects from an Sqlite database. Each Todo object has a status which can be updated by a button in it's detail view; 'complete' or 'in progress' - this then updates the SQlite database with a '1' if a Todo object has been marked as 'complete' or a '0' if it is marked as 'in progress'. This works fine I think (although it doesn't persist after quitting the application).

However, in Tab 2 I have another UITableView which I want to show only the items that have been marked as 'complete'.

Would this require another seperate Sqlite call (select * from todo where complete='1'), and then a 
seperate array of TodoFav objects to populate the table in Tab 2? If so how would Tab 2 know that Tab 1 has been updated and saved? — I think currently it only saves on exit (although again this doesn't seem to persist after a quit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been a lurker for a while now, and have searched long and hard for the answer to no avail! Many thanks.

**Edit**:

Dehydrate code to save update on exit:

```
- (void) dehydrate {
if (dirty) { // If the todo is “dirty” meaning the dirty property was set to YES, we will need   to save the new data to the database.
if (dehydrate_statment == nil) {
    const char *sql = "UPDATE todo SET priority = ?,complete =? WHERE pk=?";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &dehydrate_statment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
// Bind our variables to each of the “?”‘s.  Notice the order.  
// The numbers represent the question marks from left to right (1 being the first, 2 being the second, 3 being the third)
sqlite3_bind_int(dehydrate_statment, 3, self.primaryKey);
sqlite3_bind_int(dehydrate_statment, 2, self.status);
sqlite3_bind_int(dehydrate_statment, 1, self.priority);
int success = sqlite3_step(dehydrate_statment);

if (success != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to save priority with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_reset(dehydrate_statment);
dirty = NO;
}       
}
```

And code for button to change to complete:

```
- (void)updateStatus:(NSInteger)newStatus {
self.status = newStatus;
dirty = YES;     // Signifies that the todo has been altered and will need to be saved to the database.
}
```

Trying to query the database a second time for 'completed' (status='1') items:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)todosComplete {

NSMutableArray *todoCompleteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.todosComplete = todoCompleteArray;
[todoCompleteArray release];

NSMutableArray *retval = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *query = @"select * from todo where status='1'";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        TodoComplete *tdC = [[TodoComplete alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey database:database];
        [todosComplete addObject:tdC];
        [tdC release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
return retval;
```

}

One last thing, initialization in app delegate, seems to work fine:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
[self initializeDatabase];
//[self initializeDatabaseFiltered];

// Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window addSubview:tabController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Thanks again!!! Sorry for the long post, really appreciate any help. I know I'm missing something obvious - dehydrate needs to be instant for a start? And I'm probably not querying the db correctly for the filtered items or something!?

Comment: "I know I'm missing something obvious" - yes, yes you are. You're missing [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/FMDB), a wrapper around sqlite for objective c that makes all this `sqlite3_prepare_v2` crap unnecessary. I guarantee that if you use FMDB, 99% of your sqlite issues will magically go away.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I've had a look at FMDB a couple of times but figuring out how to actually use it was as time consuming as trying to work with SQLite directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in sqlite, but the way you're saving seems overly convoluted. I would think you could do something like the following when the save button is pushed (this is untested, my require a little syntax fixing, and I have 'buttonState' in there to indicate whether it's 0 or 1 before the button push, so adjust that accordingly...also this has the assumption that the row==the primary key, so that'll probably need an adjustment). I'm also not sure whether an open database connection lasts between methods (not saying it doesn't, just that I don't know) so when you go to recall the completed results, may need to open a DB connection [and you'd have closed it in the last method that opened it]:

```
-(void)didPushButton{
    //something to identify which indexPath.row held the button that was selected
    sqlite3 *pref = [self getNewDBConnection];
    sqlite3_stmt *progStatement = nil;
    NSString *setProg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE todo SET complete=%d WHERE pk=%d",-buttonState+1,indexPath.row];
    char * errorMsg2;
    if(sqlite3_exec(pref,[setProg UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&errorMsg2)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {NSLog(@"error setting completion");} 
    else {NSLog(@"set status for pk:%d",indexPath.row);}
    sqlite3_finalize(progStatement);
    sqlite3_close(pref);
    buttonState=-buttonState+1;
    }
```

Comment: oh, looking backwards in that tutorial, this is in part 1, is it in your project?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response and help. Yep, I already have the 'createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded' code in my app delegate, it's funny because it persists on pressing the home button but not on a complete quit. I tried adding the '[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded]' in ViewWillAppear on the RootViewController, but that crashed the app instantly! Also, I apologise for my wording regarding a second query; you are correct however Tab 2 isn't seeing the latest db update, presumably because it's not being saved instantly when changed in Tab 1? Thanks again.

Comment: it should be saved on the button press...maybe post that portion of your code as well? and are you getting any meaningful messages in your console (indicating success or failure creating the editable version of the DB)

Comment: I guess you also need to post your dehydrate method, and updateStatus method (why don't you add that code to your original post so there isn't a length concern)

Comment: I put a little code on an alternate saving approach, where you'd store the data when the button state changes

Comment: Thanks very much, I will try this now... I don't currently have a buttonState method, but I agree this way would make it much cleaner. How would the buttonState method look by default? Thanks again!!!

Comment: I think you'd need something like this in when you build the cells: `sqlite3 *load = [self getNewDBConnection];
  sqlite3_stmt *loadStatement = nil;
  NSString *loadData= @"select complete from todo where pk>0";
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(load,[loadData UTF8String],-1, &loadStatement,nil)!=SQLITE_OK){
   NSLog(@"Error preparing data query statement");
  }
  else{
   if(sqlite3_step(loadStatement)==SQLITE_ROW){    if(sqlite3_column_int(loadStatement,0)==1){[someButton setTitle:@"Complete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];} else {[someButton setTitle:@"In Progress" forState:UIControlStateNormal];}`

Comment: and then finalize the statement and close the db (also, tweak the select statement to be relevant for the particular task rather than the pk>0)